# Apply filtering on column to keep values that have specific structure

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I would like to put a condition on a column so that I only keep rows for which the values respect the following rule : 'Start with 3 caps letter followed by a number'. Whatever comes after the number is OK.

Example, if the input is :

```py
pd.Series(['LMJ5410P','PTJ9910B','C4800WI3','INJ1B','CDBBM2','ALI9920L'])
```

Then the output should be

```py
pd.Series(['LMJ5410P','PTJ9910B','INJ1B','ALI9920L'])
```

So far, here's how I proceed :

```py
def filter_rows(value) : 
  pattern = re.compile("[A-Z]{3}[0-9]")
  try : 
    if not pattern.match(value) : 
      return 'remove'
    return value
  except : 
    if type(value) == 'float' :
      return 'remove'
```

Then proceed to apply this function to my column and remove all rows with the value "remove".
Is there a more efficient way to get to the same result ?

Comment: Thanks for the reeferences.
I've edited to add my attempt, which I think works. I'm still interested in checking if there's a more efficient way to filter using that regex pattern.

Comment: `s[s.str.contains(r"^[A-Z]{3}\d")]`? I modified the close reason.

Answer (score 0):

You may match [`str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) in Python Pandas as it uses [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) that only matches the pattern at the start of the string:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(['LMJ5410P','PTJ9910B','C4800WI3','INJ1B','CDBBM2','ALI9920L'])
s[s.str.match(r"[A-Z]{3}\d")]
# 0    LMJ5410P
# 1    PTJ9910B
# 3       INJ1B
# 5    ALI9920L
# dtype: object
```

Alternatively, you may use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) (that uses [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search)), but you will need to prepend the pattern with `^` anchor (making sure the current position is start of string):

```
s[s.str.match(r"^[A-Z]{3}\d")]
```